# I have problem in terms of changing integer into character

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

[This the Instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH8tT.jpg)

I add some photo of the instruction.

But my prof wanted to change integer into character. how will I do it?
this is my code. I use my full potential in programming but this program makes me down. I use all resources i may find but I didn't get the right code

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int array[10];

void DisplayArray() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << "Array [ " << i << " ] = " << array[i] << endl;
}

void SetDefaultValues() {
  cout << "Defalut Values :" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array[i] = -1;
    cout << "array [" << i << "]"
         << "= " << array[i] << endl;
  }
}

void InsertValues() {
  cout << "Enter 10 Values " << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cin >> array[i];
  }
  cout << "\n\t\t\tArray Values Inserted...  Successfully " << endl;
}

void DeleteValues() {
  cout << "Enter the Index Number To Delete Value :";
  int index;
  cin >> index;
  if (index > 9 || index < 0) {
    cout << "Invalid Index Entered-> Valid Range(0-9)" << endl;
    DeleteValues();  // Recall The Function it self
  } else {
    array[index] = -1;
  }
  cout << "\n\t\t\tArray Value Deleted...  Successfully " << endl;
}

void UpdateValues() {
  cout << "Enter Index Number to Update Value :";
  int index;
  cin >> index;
  if (index > 9 || index < 0) {
    cout << "Invalid Index Entered-> Valid Range(0-9)" << endl;
    UpdateValues();  // Recall The Function it self
  } else {
    cout << "Enter the New Value For Index array[ " << index << " ] = ";
    cin >> array[index];
    cout << "\n\t\t\tArray Updated...  Successfully " << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  char option;
  SetDefaultValues();

  do {
    cout << "\t\t\tEnter 1 to Enter  Values\n\t\t\tEnter 2 to Update "
            "Values\n\t\t\tEnter 3 to Delete Values\n\n\t\t\t or Enter E to "
            "EXIT\n\n\t\t\t  Enter Option: ->  ";
    cin >> option;
    if (option == '1') {
      cout << "Insert Function Called" << endl;
      InsertValues();
      cout << "Inserted Values :" << endl;
      DisplayArray();
    } else if (option == '2') {
      UpdateValues();
      cout << "Updated Array :" << endl;
      DisplayArray();
    } else if (option == '3') {
      DeleteValues();
      cout << "Array After Deleting Values :" << endl;
      DisplayArray();
    } else if (option != 'e' && option != 'E') {
      cout << "\n\n\t\t\tSelect A Valid Option From Below\n\n";
    }
  } while (option != 'e' && option != 'E');

  system("cls");  // To Clear The Screen
  cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\tProgram Ended Press Any Key To Exit "
          "Screen.....\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
       << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output of my current program

```
Defalut Values :
array [0]= -1
array [1]= -1
array [2]= -1
array [3]= -1
array [4]= -1
array [5]= -1
array [6]= -1
array [7]= -1
array [8]= -1
array [9]= -1
                        Enter 1 to Enter  Values
                        Enter 2 to Update Values
                        Enter 3 to Delete Values

                          or Enter E to EXIT

                          Enter Option: ->
```

Comment: The "or linked list" part of the requirements makes me wonder at what level this assignment is being taught.

Comment: Can you add code with a better indentation? (please) :)

Comment: `<stdlib.h>` should really be `<cstdlib>`. The global array is bad. `using namespace std;` is bad practice. The design of the functions leaves a lot to be desired. The prompts should be outside of the functions that do stuff to the array, and values should be passed to most of those functions instead. You also misunderstand your requirements. There is no conversion required or needed. This is likely due to poor understanding of what an array is and how to use them.

Comment: Also, the image clearly shows that the menu selections are made with letters and **not** numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first really necessary change is to move `int array[10];` to `char array[10];`
in that way we can store characters instead of store integers.

since your program is using `std::cout` and `std::cin` (and both of them got different overloads getting a char or an integer) you don't really need to change nothing else except the default value (-1) which is an invalid character.
You may use basically a dot (`'.'`) as default value or anything else that looks good to you.

About the `search option` you can basically loop trought the array and print what positions match.

```
void SearchCharacter(char a){
    bool printed_out = false;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); ++i){
        if(array[i] == a){
            if(!printed_out){
                std::cout << "The character " << a << " is found in position: ";
                printed_out = true;
            }
            
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    
    if(printed_out)
        std::cout << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "No matches found for character: " << a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: i have problem in declaring it

Comment: what problem are you getting?